# What is the field emission current at very high voltages?

Tags: electricity, voltage, plasma-physics

Consider two planar metal electrodes at low temperature, separated by vacuum, at a given voltage (in conditions that allow electron emission from one electrode to the other).

For large voltages, the current density is predicted by Child-Langmuir's law, where the current density is proportional to $V^{3/2}$, where $V$ is the bias voltage.

What does it actually happen for very large $V$? I was wondering if at a very large $V$, the conduction band of one of the electrodes is depleted, but probably something more drastic happens before that. Does the current ever saturate?

Comment: I’m really unclear what you mean in that first sentence. Please clarify.

Comment: @JonCuster I hope now it is clearer